# Pimcore basic demo - admin blank, frontent only images and html

Tags: php, pimcore

[villa.kropec.eu](http://villa.kropec.eu)

After fresh install I get in backend blank page. If I view page source everything is fine, no errors showed up. Two ajax requests are done. But the page is not displayed. Login page is working properly.

In frontent there is a different story, html and images are loaded, but not acceptiong the css. Via dev tools i see, there are no css loaded, the request is not made.

Can somebody see this, and please, help. I am using demo-basic data.

Comment: http://villa.kropec.eu/_profiler/885198?panel=logger

Comment: http://villa.kropec.eu/_profiler/6a08b8?panel=logger

Comment: the frontend is working properly, but the backend fails, blank page

Comment: the web folder is elswhere

Comment: it would be great if you can show us network tab in your browser when you try to open admin panel, I guess some javascript fails to load